# A charset problem about parsing HTML with lxml.html

Tags: python, html, parsing, character-encoding, lxml

I've being trying to parse an html page in Python using lxml.html.

I used the following code:

```
import lxml.html as H
page = open('page.html', 'r').read()
doc = H.fromstring(page)
print H.tostring(doc)
```

The page.html is a web page I downloaded with a proxy program I wrote before which do some work about using proxy and encoding transfer. The encoding of the file has been changed to  utf-8 while the charset declaration in the page is like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

btw, gb2312 is a kind of Chinese character set.

At first, I ran the above python code, but it printed nothing but an empty html structure which is wrong and not what I wanted.

I tried some ways and at last I found the problem happened because of the charset declaration: when I replaced the 'charset=gb2312' with an empty string, the parsing code worked as I expected.

But I don't quite understand why this happen. And is the way I solved the problem the right method or just a coincidence?

Comment: related: [HTML encoding and lxml parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302125/html-encoding-and-lxml-parsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://lxml.de/parsing.html#python-unicode-strings says:

> You should generally avoid converting
>   XML/HTML data to unicode before
>   passing it into the parsers. It is
>   both slower and error prone.