# urllib2 getparam charset returns None for some sites

Tags: python, character-encoding, urllib2

I'm struggling with this for a while now. The following code snippet returns `None` for some websites even if the charset presents in the meta of header, so it doesn't seem to be a reliable way to get the proper charset of a webpage.

```
conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)
charset = conn.headers.getparam('charset')
```

I read several threads here on SO and some mentions to use `chardet` but I don't want to import an additional module if possible. Instead I'm thinking to download only the header and get the charset info by using some string functions.

Does anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conn.headers.getparam('charset')` doesn't parse html content (`<meta>` tag) it looks only in http headers (e.g., `Content-Type`).

You could [use an html parser to get the character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305248/4279) if it is not specified in http headers.

Comment: Got it and thanks! I just checked the header of the page and it doesn't contain charset at all.

Comment: If anyone interested in my solution I paste it here. I use `cssselect` of `lxml` module to get the information: `charset = site.cssselect('meta[http-equiv="Content-Type"]')[0].get('content').split("charset=",1)[1]`

Comment: @g0m3z: you should post it as your own answer. Why do you need the character encoding *after* you already completely parsed the html? Follow [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15305248/4279) that I've provided in the answer and see how the encoding is handled.

Comment: @Sebastian Maybe you are right and I do something wrong. I use `parse.getroot()` function of `xhtml` which returns an `HTMLelement` object and I get the relevant information from this `HTMLelement` object by applying some xpath expressions on it, which returns some specific characters that need to be encoded properly. Is it an incorrect approach?

Comment: @g0m3z: it is incorrect approach if your strings are already Unicode  (look at the strings returned by lxml). Note: On Python 2, lxml may use `str` type if a string is ascii-only (an optimization of some kind).

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment here and post it as an answer.

Thanks to @J.F. Sebastian I could get the charset from meta tag by using the below code snippet:

```
conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
site = parse(conn).getroot()
charset = site.cssselect('meta[http-equiv="Content-Type"]')[0].get('content').split("chars‌​et=",1)[1]
```

Comment: It is *not* what I've suggested [follow the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15305248/4279). (I don't want to copy-paste the answer verbatim).

Comment: Maybe my understanding is not correct with regards to encoding/decoding. What I'm trying to achieve is to garb data from 3 different websites/encodings and store those in an SQLite DB. The reason why I posted my original question was that I print all data to screen for debugging reason and the result was hex stream in case of those charasters which are in unicode (e.g.: \xef\xb6\x9b). Maybe it's not an issue at all or only an issue with the representation of data on screen and I could store data in DB as it present on the website. Do I need to decode data at all? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: if you follow the code in the link then you should be able to get your data as a Unicode string. If you can't; provide a complete minimal example that shows the issue. If you have problems with displaying unicode or saving it into a database, ask another question.