# How to get unicode string when extract data in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping

I am trying to extract text from a Vietnamese website, which charset is in utf-8. However, the text I got is always in Ascii, and I can't find a way to convert them to unicode or get exactly the text on the website. As a result, I can't save them into file as expected. 
I know this is the very popular problem with unicode in Python, but I still hope someone will help me to figure it out. Thanks. 
My code:

```
import requests, re, io
import simplejson as json
from lxml import html, etree

base = "http://www.amthuc365.vn/cong-thuc/"
page = requests.get(base + "trang-" + str(1) + ".html")
pageTree = html.fromstring(page.text)

links = pageTree.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "mt30")]/li/a/@href')
names = pageTree.xpath('//h3[@class="title"]/a/text()')
for name in names[:1]:
    print name
    # LÃ m bÃ¡nh oreo nhÃ¢n bÆ¡ Äáº­u phá»ng thÆ¡m bÃ¹i
```

but what I need is "Làm bánh oreo nhân bơ đậu phộng thơm bùi" 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switching from `page.text` to `page.content` should make it work.

Explanation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content).

Also see:

- [What is the difference between 'content' and 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011357/what-is-the-difference-between-content-and-text)
- [HTML encoding and lxml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302125/html-encoding-and-lxml-parsing)

Comment: Thank you very much @alecxe